# how to get size of table field trough oracle Query

Tags: oracle

I want to get size of Oracle table field(Column), I try below query

```
 select data_type, data_length 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'CRM_CHANGE_REQ'
   and column_name = 'RNO';
```

it gives 22 but real size is 4,so give suggestion what can i do?

Comment: check DATA_PRECISION and DATA_SCALE. DATA_PRECISION will be 4 in your case. DATA_SCALE gives the decimal part. In your case it will be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:10153966194688

DATA_LENGTH column stores maximum length in bytes required to *store* values for a datatype of a given column.

For NUMBER it is always 22 bytes, regardless of the precision and scale (1 byte for exponent, 20 bytes for a mantissa and 1 byte for negative sign).

For NUMBER datatype you should look at DATA_PRECISION and DATA_SCALE columns if you want to 
find the precision and scale defined for a column.

Comment: 1 Byte or bit for negative?